# How do I use handle_cast and handle_call in Erlang gen_server?

Tags: erlang

As far as I understand, I should use `handle_cast` for asynchronous requests, by sending messages, then react to response via `receive..end` on client side.

Here is an example:

```
Pid ! {auth_user, {User, Password}}.
```

For synchronous requests, when I want to wait when `gen_server` sends a response, I must explicitly call the respective function from the module like this:

```
{ok, Result} = auth_server:auth_user({User, Password}).
```

Are the statements from above are correct?

If the latter is correct, why then I need a construction like this if I already have an exported function `auth_user`?

```
handle_call({authenticate_user, {Login, Password}}, _From, _) ->
    {reply, {}, {}}.
```

Comment: if you send a message via `Pid ! {auth_user, {User, Password}}.`, it will trig the callback `Mod:handle_info({auth_user, {User, Password}}, State)`

Comment: In addition to dogberts answer: Unfortunately you have to learn two concepts in erlang, for one the language itself where you write your receive..end loops yourself, and then OTP-Style that hides this low-level layer from you and introduces a different programming model (callbacks), but is worth using  since it handles a lot of edge cases.

Answer (score 5):

You don't interact with a `gen_server` by sending messages directly like that. You should use `gen_server:call` or `gen_server:cast` like this:

```
Response = gen_server:call(Pid, {auth_user, {User, Password}})
```

`call` / `cast` will handle sending the message to the `Pid` (and receiving a response for `call`) itself, along with many edge cases like the process crashing before responding to your request, etc.

> If the latter is correct, why then I need a construction like this if I already have an exported function `auth_user`?

`gen_server` is useful when you want to keep some state stored between multiple calls. For example, if you want to keep a global counter of the number of pageviews in your app in memory, you should use `gen_server`, store the counter as the state of the and make a `cast` or `call` to it on each request. If you don't have a state to keep, you should use normal functions.

Comment: AFAIK, it's a bad practice in Erlang world not to use OTP when the tools are already there. Or at least, to suggest it to new-comers. I'm a new-comers myself, so take this as a side question from me.